# DOM traverse up across more than 1 parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: facebook DOM]

I want to traverse all the way up to mbm class, I do like this

`$('.mtm ._5cq3').prevUntil('.mbm')` but it target nothing. I tried parents and closest, I'm confused now.

Comment: you can try to use el.parentNode reference to check is parent contains class mbm or not, like this: function findParent(el, cls){
    if(!el.parentNode) return false;
    
    if(el.parentNode.classList && el.parentNode.classList.contains(cls)) return el.parentNode;
    
    return findParent(el.parentNode, cls);
}

Comment: @Dart I console the selector it show the body, so need no to do node checking, something is wrong with my traverse I guess.

Comment: see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lsxv2da/ or here http://jsfiddle.net/5Lsxv2da/1/ or provide you HTML

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong, here is the working fiddle with `.closest`:

http://jsfiddle.net/15dffhx9/

Could you tell us what your console is showing, when using `console.log($('.mtm ._5cq3').closest('.mbm'));`?

Comment: closest will traverse all the way up?

Comment: Yes. Please check "http://api.jquery.com/closest/" for a documentation of .closest